# Different Ways to Say "Hometown"

Tags: word-choice, meaning, usage

I have encountered both `老家` and `家乡` for referring to one's hometown.  What are the differences?  That is: When should each one be used?  When should one or the other be avoided?  When can they both be used interchangeably?

**EDIT:** The terms `故乡` and `祖籍` (or `籍贯`), meaning *home of my ancestors*, have been introduced as additional ways to express the same idea. [ *Question title updated.* ]

Comment: 乡 is village. 家乡 refers to the village that you grew up in and which you may still be staying occasionally. In present times, 乡 is also known as a township. 老家 doesn't usually have such connotation; it just refers to the house you grew up in, and which you no longer stay now. 故乡 and 祖籍 are very formal words. 故 refers to the past. Use 故乡 only when you have uprooted yourself permanently from this place to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have the same meaning, but `家乡` is more formal than `老家`.  I am Chinese; when writing, we use `家乡` in our essays.  When speaking, we often use this phrase `我从《PLACE》来`, which means `I come from《PLACE》`.

Comment: Can you include some examples on how 家乡 and 老家 are used?

Comment: Are there any situations where one or the other would be "wrong"?

Comment: Usually in a conversation people ask `你老家是哪里的?' It would sound very strange to ask `你的家乡是哪里?' in a casual conversation.

Comment: The example of "老家"：我的老家在“Place”。The example of "家乡"：我的家乡是“Place”。Like @user58955 says， we use "你的老家是哪里的？"or "你从哪里来的？" when we chatting with friends.@Andrew Kozak Since these two words have the similar meaning, using either "老家" or “家乡” will be both ok in most situations.

Comment: @Jing Can you comment on the usage of `故乡`?

Comment: `故乡` is more likely to be used when you have moved to another city for quite a while from your hometown, and the word conveys a sense of nostalgia. I don't think 老家 and 家乡 carry that much nostalgic connotation.

Answer (score 3):

To me, either of 老家, 家乡, or 故乡 gives similar meaning, any of one doesn't not necessarily mean the home that I'm living in currently, nor other implications. Context can determine the implied meaning. All of them can be used as written expression, and also can be heard often. 故乡 seems to be the most formal among these three.

Another one, 祖籍 (or 籍贯), is quite definite: home of my ancestor, usually being a different one from my current home.

Comment: I have not encountered `故乡`.  Could you explain the distinctive formality a little more?

Comment: I don't seem to agree with you. First, you mentioned 故乡, what about "低头思故乡"? Then you pointed out that 祖籍 and 籍贯 were the same thing. Maybe you come from a different background (not the mainland)?

Comment: 低头思故乡 is quite formal, isn't it. Formal in a sense as not so casual. I never say 祖籍 and 籍贯 are the same. Each and every word has something different, at least the form. I was born in Chongqing.

Comment: The reason I mentioned "低头思故乡" is that 故乡 can only mean a place where we used to live but not where we live.

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: For example, I can tell my friend 小明 that "因为这里我的故乡! (Because here is my root!)" when I'm living in my home, after a few years of traveling abroad, as an answer to 小明's puzzle ("Why not just living abroad ever after?"). It's quite okay if this example happens to be on my memoir, kind of formal.

Answer (score 2):

They sound different to me, although they both mean a place where one grows up. When one says 老家, he does not live there any more. 家乡 does not have such connotations.

Comment: So, something like `我还住在我的老家。` wouldn't be appropriate because the speaker still lives in his hometown?  In this case, are you saying that it is better to use `家乡`?

Comment: @AndrewKozak I think so.